# Second monitor available without beeing connected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, laptop, external-monitor

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my Laptop, and everything worked better than thought, but:

My laptop recognises two screens. I mean, you can connect a second screen to it by HDMI or VGA, but both connectors are empty the whole time.

What could it bet?

The laptop uses a nVidia GT 520M and an Intel HD300 Graphics card. How to fix that?

Comment: Could you add to your post the output of the command `xrandr -q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by Both Connectors are empty the whole time? Did you update the Nivida Drivers?

For Ubuntu 12.04 Open your Terminal and run the code below and it may resolve your issue if I understand it correctly.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Alternatively you can go to **System Settings**, **hardware, additional drives**.  The system should search for additional drivers that need to be updated

-Govna